# Using full stop as string delimiter in Stringtokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I would like to exclude full stop `.` from string tokens like in the following case:

```
 I go to school.
```

Would like to generate tokens as:

```
        [ I] [go] [to] [school]
```

I used stringTokenizer as:

```
List<String> listStr = new ArrayList<String>();
StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(str);                    
int i =0;
while(strToken.hasMoreTokens()){
    listStr.add(i, strToken.nextToken());
    i=i+1;
}
```

But the last token is `school.` which i don;t want. How would i do it?

Comment: using a regex with `replace()` or `replaceAll()` method should do, or have I misunderstood the questions?

Comment: Btw, you increment `i` is not needed. Just use the `add(Object)` and it will automatically be added to the end of your list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StringTokenizer has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that takes another argument: The characters that act as delimiters. The following code illustrates this:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("I go to school.", " \t\r\n.");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextElement());
}
```

This is the output, which should be what you want:

```
I
go
to
school
```

Answer (score 5):

Isn't this simpler?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("I go to school.".split("[ .]"));
```

`System.out.println(list)` prints

```
[I, go, to, school]
```

Comment: Yes it is simpler. Else, if he/she wants to keep the StringTokenizer, use this constructor: `new StringTokenizer(str," \t\f\r\n.");`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on the initial string: `string.replace(".", "")` then do the tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

StringTokenizer can take a lot of delimiters, so now in your case you should build the strink tokenizer the following way:

```
new StringTokenizer(yourString, " .");
```

And thats it.

Hope it helps.